# What features can be used when installing sysrepo modules?

Tags: c, libyang

To install a sysrepo module via code you can use the call `sr_install_module()` with the following parameters:

```
API int
sr_install_module(sr_conn_ctx_t *conn,
                  const char *schema_path,
                  const char *search_dirs,
                  const char **features)
```

Which options can be used for `features` in here?